# merge two strings of different sizes in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, merge

How can I merge character by character two strings of different sizes to the n-th element of `A` and m-th element of `B`. I can easily do it when they have the same size (assuming here `n=m`). But cannot figure out how to handle this exception.

My working `zip` code is as follows:

```
char * zip(char *A, char *B, int n)
{
    char *C;
    int i;

    C = malloc((2*n) * sizeof *A);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
            C[(2*i)]=A[i];
            C[(2*i)+1]=B[i];
    }

    return C;
}
```

But instead to pass just `int n`, I would like to pass also `int m` where `n` is to merge the `n` first elements of `A` and the `m` first elements of `B`. Hence  passing the following input to the `new_zip(char *A, char *B, int n, int m)`.  `A="rslxyzkw"; B="eutingxyz";n=3; m=6`, I would get `"resulting"`.

Comment: You don't seem to take the null terminator in account, or is that included with `n`? That is, does `n` represent array sizes or string lengths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

char *new_zip(char *A, char *B, int n, int m){
    assert(A != NULL && B != NULL && n >= 0 && m >= 0);
    char *C = malloc(n + m + 1);//+1 for NUL
    if(!C){
        perror("malloc:");
        return NULL;
    }
    int i = 0;

    while(n + m > 0){
        if(n > 0 && *A){
            C[i++] = *A++;
            --n;
        }
        if(m > 0 && *B){
            C[i++] = *B++;
            --m;
        }
    }
    C[i] = 0;
    return C;
}

int main (void){
    char *result = new_zip("rslxyzkw", "eutingxyz", 3, 6);
    printf("'%s'\n", result);
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping until a certain length you can loop until you run out of characters.  C strings have a null character at the end so after you allocate the memory you can loop as long as both aren't a null character.  All you need to do then is only add non-null characters to your output string.

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc, free */
#include <string.h> /* strlen */

char *zip(char *a, char *b)
{
    char *c = malloc( (strlen(a)+strlen(b)+1) * sizeof(char) ), *p = c;
    if(c)
    {
      while(*a || *b) /* while either string has characters */
      {
        if(*a) *p++ = *a++; /* add a character from a if non-null */
        if(*b) *p++ = *b++; /* add a character from b if non-null */
      }
      *p='\0'; /* finish the string with a null character */
    }
    return c;
}

int main()
{
  char *a = "This is a string";
  char *b = "This is another longer string";
  char *c = zip(a,b);
  if(c)
  {
    printf("zip(%s,%s) = %s\n",a,b,c);
    free(c);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really enjoyed your simplicity and clarity. But your solution lacked of the `n` and `m` restriction, for SO rules, I'm inclined to mark @BLUEPIXY solution as right one.

Answer (score 0):

The following could work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* zip(char* A, char* B) {
    char *C;
    int k = 0;

    C = (char*)malloc(strlen(A)+strlen(B)+1);

    while (*A != '\0' || *B != '\0') {
        if (*A != '\0') {
            C[k++] = *A;
            ++A;
        }
        if (*B != '\0') {
            C[k++] = *B;
            ++B;
        }
    }
    C[k] = '\0';

    return C;
}



int main() {
    char *A = "123456", *B = "abcd", *C;

    C = zip(A, B);

    puts(C);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code would work in the following way:

First do alternate merging from strings s1 and s2 based on the minimum value of m and n.
The second part would take care of appending the remaining elements either from s1 or from s2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* merge (char *s1, char *s2, int m, int n)
{
    char *s = (char *) malloc(m + n + 1);

    int min = (m < n)? m: n;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    int count = 0;

    /* Alternate merge from s1 and s2 to s*/
    while (count < 2 * min) {
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            s[k++] = s1[i++];
        } else {
            s[k++] = s2[j++];
        }
        count++;
    }

    /* Append the remaining elements from s1 or s2 to s*/
    if (m > min) {
        for (count = 0; count < m - min; count++) {
            s[k++] = s1[i++];
        }
    } else if (n > min) {
        for (count = 0; count < n - min; count++) {
            s[k++] = s2[j++];
        }
    }
    s[k++] = '\0';
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    char *s1 = "rslxyzkw";
    char *s2 = "eutingxyz";

    char *s = merge(s1, s2, 3, 6);
    printf ("%s\n", s);
}
```